# How Cassandra token rings work

Tags: cassandra

I am in doubt about how cassandra partition data accross the cluster.
Accorind to `nodetool status` my cassandra have 2048 tokens in 2 datacenters. I assume that it divides the info in 1024 identical token ranges in each DC right?
Anyway, those 1024 tokens is for all CFs or each CF has 1024 token ranges?

Comment: What is the value of `num_tokens` in your cassandra.yaml?

Comment: `num_tokens: 128`

Comment: Each node in the datacenter will be given 128 tokens. its not DC specific it depends on how many nodes each DC have. Going by the number your cluster should have 16 nodes. Token ranges are not CF specific they are for the entire cluster

Comment: But the write is DC aware right? each DC is identical to the other? I assume that all my data is replicated between those 2 DCs, if all the nodes of 1 DC goes down my data will still be ok because one of the DCs still online? in that case each DC has a token ring replicated?

Answer (score 0):

There are 16 nodes in your cluster
128 token ranges * 16 nodes nodes = 2048 token ranges

Each datacenter has their own ring of tokens depending on the number of nodes in each datacenter. For example, a datacenter with 10 nodes would have their token ring divided into 128*10 segments.

Each column family will use all of these ranges to distribute data within the datacenter.

For example, a datacenter with 3 token ranges would mean that each individual write will be placed either on token range 1,2 or 3. Another column family would follow this same standard.